# Envoking Dock or Workspaces freeze after waking up computer

Tags: 22.04, freeze, workspaces, dock

After waking up the computer, moving the mouse down to the dock or evoking the workspaces (ctrl + alt + > or "Windows" key) results in a black screen. The only fix is to restart or log out.

Ubuntu 22.04
HP Folio 9470

[Black screen after scrolling to Dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWwuf.jpg)

[Truncated dock seen after waking computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppHUv.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Cause: Conflict between "Ubuntu Dock" and "Dash To Dock."

Solution: Turn off Ubuntu Doc in System Extensions.

There may be a conflict between the default Ubuntu Dock for the Gnome Shell and Dash To Dock if **BOTH** are activated.

The Ubuntu Dock extension is a modified version of Dash To Dock with different defaults. Dash To Dock can be installed to replace it and give more (but unsupported) configuration options.

I had both installed and turned on. I turned off Ubuntu Dock and have not experienced the issue since.

[Screenshot of extensions panel confgued correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAoTh.png)